# Wi-fi problem encountered by new Ubuntu user

Tags: wireless

I am new to Ubuntu and, I just installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my old surface pro 1. Everything seems fine, yet when I try to connect to home wifi, Ubuntu keeps asking for the password and just won't connect, even though I have typed the correct password. Can anyone offer any help?

Comment: Did you try rebooting?

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your network manager by running

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

let me know if that does not work...